# Aggregating one column based on another pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This should technically be a simple thing to do, but unfortunately its eluding my mind at the moment.

I'm trying to find the proportion of another column based on another column. eg:

```
Column 1   |  target_variable
'potato'         1
'potato'         0
'tomato'         1
'brocolli'       1
'tomato'         0
```

Intended output would be:

```
column 1   | target = 1  | target = 0 | total_count
'potato'   |     1       |      1     |     2
'tomato'   |     1       |      1     |     2
'brocolli' |     1       |      0     |     1
```

However, I think I'm using aggregate wrongly, so I resort to the following naive implementation:

```
z = {}
for i in train.index:
    fruit = train["fruit"][i]
    l = train["target"][i]
    if fruit not in z:
        if l == 1:
            z[fruit] = {1:1,0:0,'count':1}
        else:
            z[fruit] = {1:0,0:1,'count':1}
    else:
        if l == 1:
            z[fruit][1] += 1
        else:
            z[fruit][0] += 1
        z[fruit]['count'] += 1
```

Which gives a similar output in a dictionary form instead.

Can anyone enlighten me on the proper syntax for the pandas way? :)

Thank you! :)

Comment: Is output correct?

Comment: @jezrael Whoops sorry, fixed! :) thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Output is changed if is added another row `'potato' ,1` ?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? @jezrael potato should have 1 : 2 and 0: 1 then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) + [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) + [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Column 1','target_variable']).size() \
        .unstack(fill_value=0) \
        .add_prefix('target = ')
df1['total_count'] = df1.sum(axis=1)
print (df1)
target_variable  target = 0  target = 1  total_count
Column 1                                            
brocolli                  0           1            1
potato                    1           1            2
tomato                    1           1            2
```

Or [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Column 1'],df['target_variable'], margins=True)
print (df1)
target_variable  0  1  All
Column 1                  
brocolli         0  1    1
potato           1  1    2
tomato           1  1    2
All              2  3    5

df1 = df1.rename(columns = {'All': 'total_count'}).iloc[:-1]
print (df1)
target_variable  0  1  total_count
Column 1                          
brocolli         0  1            1
potato           1  1            2
tomato           1  1            2
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `get_dummies`, `add_prefix` and `groupby`:

```
df = df.assign(**df['target_variable'].astype(str).str.get_dummies().add_prefix('target = '))
df['total_count'] = df.drop('target_variable', axis=1).sum(axis=1)
df.groupby('Column 1').sum()
```

Output:

```
            target_variable  target = 0  target = 1  total_count
Column 1                                                        
'brocolli'                1           0           1            1
'potato'                  1           1           1            2
'tomato'                  1           1           1            2
```